# Site optimization prior to deployment

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm finishing my Joomla site soon. 
I have:
1. Removed unnecessary images from site folder.
2. Unpublished unnecessary modules, articles, categories.

What any other optimizations can be done in order my site to load faster?
It feels that it is loading a little bit slower.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a similar question to [Site clean up tips](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15009/120) although not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement:

- Enable **Gzip** compression in the global configuration.
- Optimize the images on your site, a tool like [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) or tinyjpg.com can
  be very useful.
- Once your site is finished, don't forget to consider enabling the cache.
- Once your site is finished, consider use some CDN.
- Other useful online services: gtmetrix.com, webpagetest.org
- Exra to the extensions, you can add manualy some code in your .htaccess
  file, here find a block with the title "**Begin - Optimal default expiration time**".
  https://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_(security)

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of things that can be done.

---

#### Step 1:

Update to Joomla 3.5

I've have just done this on all my sites and the back-end especially is so much faster at executing database queries.

---

#### Step 2:

If you can update your server's PHP version to 7, then do so. The performance increase is very big. But make sure your extensions are PHP7 compatible.

---

#### Step 3:

Look into caching your CSS/JS files and images. I'd recommend using [JCH Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jch-optimize). When going through the setting available, don't simply switch everything to the max as you'll run into issues. Try each one individually, each time checking your browser console to see if any errors occur.

---

#### Step 4:

Use a 3rd party Speed Test tool. I personally recommend [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/). After running a test, it will tell you what you're currently doing wrong on your site and how to fix/improve it. Another site you can also use is [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/)

---

Hope this helps

Comment: Enable caching are making significant faster loads too. And enabling gzip compression.

Comment: Nice answer. The only thing I'd add is to remove any third party extensions (especially plugins) that are not being used.